# session value changes after changing of associated variable

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a code for cart using session. In shopping cart page I assigned the variable to session for fetch the cart and show it but when I change some values of variable, my session changed automatically and in next refresh of page, my session values updated.

I'm using laravel 5.

And this is my code:

```
  $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
  foreach($oldCart as  $cartRow):
    foreach($cartRow as $crKey => $row):
      $oldCart->totalPrice -= 2000;
      $oldCart->items[$crKey]['price'] -= 1000;
      endforeach;
  endforeach;
```

In code above, The value of 'total price' in session decreases 1000 in each refresh of page but I don't want to change any value of session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working on a reference and when you change value you also modify the session object (and it changes the session).

Try to clone the object before you modify it.

```
$oldCart = clone Session::get('cart');
```